# How to diff two folders to multiple patch files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, diff

I'm not much of a unix guy so I'll just go ahead and ask:

I have a following problem - two folders with plenty of subfolders. I need to diff them.

I tried this:

```
diff -drupN vanila_kernel_3.0.8 my_kernel_3.0.8 > kernel.patch
```

and that results in a 85mb file... and not really what I want.

I want the result of the diff to be many smaller patches, ideally one for every changed file with the contents of the change. That means I have t ochange the way I use diff, and I need to put it in some sort of a loop... So i tried running this little script

```
for file in original_308/*.*; do
    diff -dupN "$file" "my_308/${file##*/}" > "$file".patch
done
```

But it doesn't work :/

Ideally, I want to have a .patch file for every change, but having patches for files that changed in original would do just fine (as I could filter the newly added files and just copy them over)

Can someone provide me with a decent way to do this please?

EDIT:

Here's something choroba asked me to post

```
diff -Naur -x '*.o' -x '*.cmd' -x '*.d' original_308/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S my_308/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S
--- original_308/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S    2011-10-25 07:11:12.000000000 +0200
+++ my_308/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S  2012-07-04 03:57:25.000000000 +0200
@@ -656,6 +656,8 @@
@       b   __arm6_mmu_cache_off
@       b   __armv3_mmu_cache_flush
```

So yes, it is the proper output even though gedit/geany cannot open it. UltraEdit does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the original format that creates the huge diff file which you can subsequently split into the small files. You might be interested in `csplit` for the splitting, or you can use a scripting language like Perl:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^diff -drupN (.*) (.*)/) {
              my $f = $1;
              $f =~ s{/}{_}g;
              open $FH, ">", "$f.patch" or die $!;
          } else {
              print {$FH} $_;
          }' kernel.patch
```

If you need the `diff` line in each file, add the `print` after the `open`.

Comment: I really don't know anything about perl, can i paste this into a mydiff.sh file and execute it in shell? Also, since this language is somewhat unreadable to me, will it generate a .patch file for every ALTERED file between the two folders?

Comment: Yes, pasting this into your shell script or command prompt should be safe. It will create a patch file for each pair in the current working directory, for a file named `a/b.c` the patch will be called `a_b.c.patch`. I did not post a more readable version of the solution as it would take much more space.

Comment: It didn't work for me :/ does it traverse the directory tree and call diff for each file there or what? I don't even know why it doesn't work... And please take up some more space.

Comment: @Shark: It operates on the file created by `diff -drupN ...`. Have you created it?

Comment: I have this in my folder: original_308, my_308, your_diff.sh, kernel.patch.

I have found there to be 231 different files, i want those 231 .patch files to end up in a patches/ folder somehow or just following the folder structure.

Comment: So just run it and then `mv original*.patch patches/`.

Comment: Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at -e line 6, <> line 1.

I don't get it... how about a script that runs diff on FOLDER1/file and FOLDER2/file where i read the 'file' from a list of changed files?

Comment: `kernel.patch` is probably not the ouput from `diff -drupN original_308 my_308`

Comment: I don't want to sound rude or anything but how about you edit your script/answer to fit my data/requirement instead of me trying to fit in with something I cant even read/understand? Because it is the output from diff -drupN (same with -Naur) original_308 my_308 > kernel.patch

Comment: @Shark: Can you show the first several lines of the `kernel.patch`?

Comment: yes, i updated my question with the proper information.

Comment: @Shark: OK, just change the `if` condition to `/^diff .* (.*) (.*)/`

Comment: syntax error at -e line 1, near "/^diff -drupN (.*) (.*)/ {"
Can't use global $1 in "my" at -e line 2, near "= $1"
syntax error at -e line 5, near "} else"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Shark: There is no `-drupN` in my new version.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a small Perl script to patch the files. This script is very basic, which goes through the directories recursively and fetch the file and creates a diff.

```
Usage: script_name.pl <source_dir> <dest_dir> <dir_2_create_diffs>
```

testpatch.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;
my $source = $ARGV[0];
my $dest = $ARGV[1];
my $pathdir = $ARGV[2];

unless (defined $ARGV[2]) { print "Usage: $0 <source> <dest> <patch_directory>\n"; exit 0; }
my @alldir;
find sub {
     return if -d;
     push @alldir, $File::Find::name;
}, "$source";
for my $path ( @alldir) {
     my @tmp = split ("/",$path); my $rmt_dir = shift(@tmp); 
     my $fpath = join("/",@tmp);  my $fn = $tmp[-1];
     pop(@tmp); my $strp_path = join("/",@tmp);
     `mkdir -p $pathdir/$strp_path` unless( -d "$pathdir/$strp_path");
     `diff -dupN $path $dest$fpath > $pathdir/$strp_path/$fn.patch`;
}
```

Sample usage: `$ ./testpatch.pl original_308/ tmp/ tmp1`

I created sample files( header.cpp, head1.S, head.S)

- original_308/arch/arm/boot:header.cpp
- original_308/arch/arm/boot/compressed:head1.S  head.S
- tmp/arch/arm/boot:header.cpp
- tmp/arch/arm/boot/compressed:head1.S 
  head.S

After running the script, the diffs were created in a new dir "tmp1"

Output:

- tmp1/arch/arm/boot:header.cpp.patch
- tmp1/arch/arm/boot/compressed: head1.S.patch  head.S.patch

Hope this helps.